# Salesforce Object with _hd suffix?

Tags: custom-object, metadata

I am coming across an underscore hd ( _hd ) object in my instance, Ive not noticed this before?

I have a custom object called Membershi__c

I also see the following to additional objects

- Membership__History
- **Membership__c_hd**

The History object I know is for file history tracking.

**Does anyone know what the _hd object is, it is not query-able, I see it in the developer console object list**

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The _hd suffix stands in for 'Historical Data'. When [Historical Trending](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_historical_setup.htm&language=en_US) is set up for an object, the customobject__c_hd will show up in the Developer Console. There isn't much in the way of documentation on how Salesforce is handling this on the backend that I can find, just the Setup and Reporting documentation linked above.

Comment: Thanks peter, yes that looks like it. We'd enabled it in error and was consuming lost of data store.

Answer (score 9):

Here is some more detail on `__hd` SObjects:

I enabled Opportunity with Historical trending on 2015-03-12. I took one of my Opportunities where there had been changes in Amount over time and executed this query:

```
SELECT ValidFromDate,ValidToDate, Amount__hpr,Amount__hst,ParentId 
   FROM Opportunity__hd where parentid = '006d000000Q0dxiAAB'
```

Observe the results:

[image]

What you see is a row for many datetime ranges reflecting changes made to the Opportunity

- `Amount__hpr` is the value at the start of the Datetime range
- `Amount__hst` is the value at the end of the Datetime range
- `ParentId` is the parent object being tracked with historical trending

Note also that even though I enabled Opportunity with Historical Trending on 2015-03-12; SFDC went back in time and (presumably) looked at my Field History tracking to populate the rows prior to 2015-03-12

Why are there seemingly duplicate rows where the Amount didn't change from range1 to range2?

By repeating the query but this time including the other fields being tracked, we see that a row is written to `Opportunity__hd` every time one of the tracked fields changes. When the row is written, all of the (up to 8) tracked fields' previous/current value since the last row written are emitted in a new row.

One begins to see why SFDC limits this to up to 8 tracked fields and only up to 3 months of historical data.

```
SELECT ValidFromDate,ValidToDate,
       Amount__hpr, Amount__hst,
       CloseDate__hpr,CloseDate__hst,
       Forecast_Status__c_hpr,Forecast_Status__c_hst,
       ParentId 
  FROM Opportunity__hd where parentId ='006d000000Q0dxiAAB'
```

[image]