# What are the object and field name suffixes that Salesforce uses? Such as __c and __x

Tags: api, custom-object, custom-metadata

When working with API names for objects and fields they will often have suffixes such as `__c` and `__x`.

What suffixes are there and what do these API name suffixes indicate?

Comment: Do you mind if I convert this to `[canonical-qa]` and make both posts wikis?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sure. This question and answer can be changed to a wiki to help with future updates from the community.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

This is the list I've compiled. Feel free to add any I've missed.

- `__c` Custom Object or Custom field
- `__r` Custom relationship field as used in a SOQL query to traverse the relationship
- `__ka` [KnowledgeArticle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticle.htm#topic-title)
- `__kav` [KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm#topic-title)
- `__Feed` [Article Type Feed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_articletype__feed.htm#topic-title) or Custom Object Feed
- `__ViewStat` [KnowledgeArticleViewStat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleviewstat.htm#topic-title)
- `__VoteStat` [KnowledgeArticleVoteStat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm#topic-title)
- `__DataCategorySelection` [Article Type__DataCategorySelection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_articletype__datacategoryselection.htm#sforce_api_objects_articletype__datacategoryselection)
- `__x` [External Object](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=xorg_api_names.htm&language=en_US)
- `__xo` Salesforce-to-Salesforce (S2S) spoke/proxy object
- `__mdt` [Custom Metadata Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_custommetadatatype__mdt.htm)
- `__Share` [Custom object sharing object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)
- `__Tag` [Salesforce Tags](http://www.shellblack.com/administration/salesforce-tags-the-good-the-bad-limitations-and-the-future/)
- `__History` [Field History Tracking for Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&language=en_US)
- `__pc` Custom Person Account Field
- `__pr` Used for traversing custom Person Account relationship fields
- `__hd` [Historical Data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/31398/102)
  `__hqr`, `__hst` Start/End of the Datetime range
- `__b` [BigObject](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/14/en-us/sfdc/pdf/big_object_impl_guide.pdf)
- `__latitude__s` [Geolocation Latitude Coordinate](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm&language=en)
- `__longitude__s` [Geolocation Longitude Coordinate](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm&language=en)
- `__e` [Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/) - a.k.a. EventBus event ([Winter `17 pilot](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_api_messaging.htm#rn_api_messaging_platform_events?edition=&impact=))
- `__p` Custom Person Object ([Spring `15 pilot](http://www.salesforce.org/custom-person-object/))
- `__ChangeEvent` Change Data Capture ([Winter `19 Dev Preview](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_data_change_events.htm))
- `__chn` Change Event channel ([Source](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_change_data_capture_enrichment.htm))
- `__dlm` Data Lake Model, from the customer data platform ([Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/04/how-to-query-data-from-customer-360-audiences))

Comment: @Erik, thanks for adding the Person Account fields.

Comment: Well done. I would vote twice if I could.

Comment: @Peter. Thanks. I was inspired by @metadaddy's and @jonbruce's BigObject presentation today. Which made me realize, I've missed `__b`!

Comment: __md was only used in a developer preview of custom metadata records-- it's no longer used (although __mdt for types is).

Comment: Also _del for deleted fields?

Comment: @powlo Is that an actual suffix, or is it just appended to the custom field name before the `__c`? I ask because I haven't seen one before and the docs in [Managing Deleted Custom Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_managing_deleted_fields.htm) show only one underscore, which makes me wonder if it is slightly different.

Comment: @DanielBallinger you're correct. It's <field>_del__c

Comment: @DanielBallinger This should probably be a Community Wiki.

Comment: I'm adding `__pr`, the `__r` equivalent for Person Account fields.

Comment: More love...I'm working up a blog post for SOQL newbies and plan to link to this answer @DanielBallinger

Comment: Question: Do parent relationship fields only come in the 3 formats: 1) field suffixed with `Id`, relationship has no suffix; 2) field suffixed with `__c`, relationship with `__r`; 3) field suffixed with `__pc`, relationship with `__pr`? Or do any of these other patterns apply to parent relationship names?