# How can read/modify person account NetId?

Tags: person-accounts

How can read/modify person account NetId? I could not find any reference to this particular person account information. Is this located as some Account field? (I could not find this one also)

Answer (score 0):

I found the field:  Net_ID__pc

Comment: See also: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101844/what-are-the-object-and-field-name-suffixes-that-salesforce-uses-such-as-c-an/101845#101845