# What kind of Object is Charts__History

Tags: apex, custom-object, metadata-api, workbench

In an Org I am trying to find the metadata of an object with api - `Charts__History`(Yes, with no `__c`). I could not find it in Salesforce Org UI so I used workbench to investigate.

I can run the query editor and I get a result. I am trying to add some value for this object as it has been used in a test class. Below is what I get from query editor:

[image]

From WorkBench:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What could be this metadata and what can I try to create a record related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable [Field History Tracking for a Custom Object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&type=5), a new object will be available to track these changes. This new object will have the same API Name as your custom object, except it will have the `__history` suffix instead of `__c`. You will need to change a tracked field and commit the update in order for such changes to show up in your database.

See also: [What are the object and field name suffixes that Salesforce uses? Such as __c and __x](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/101845/2995)

Comment: You might need to use `SeeAllData` for the tracked `__history` record to appear during your test. I'll have to double check.

Comment: Creating or modifying data in a test class or method with `@seeAllData` does not create field tracking history (just tried on cs14). See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198260/deserialize-history-record-with-read-only-fields) for a discussion on how to create field tracking records in test classes (hint: its a nightmare).

Comment: Well at least with that annotation you can query existing records without needing to create them yourself.

Comment: I create a record and changed the field that is been tracked. Used a query to retrieve __History but did not see any record returned. I tried with seeAllData as well. I might be missing something?

Comment: As per my above comment, modifying records in a test context will not create a field tracking history record. You can vote on an idea to change this behavior [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h6RwAAI). If you have a specific use case where you need to cover some section of code which relies on existing field history records, I'd suggest [asking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question instead of trying to change the scope of an existing question.